# Loading dynamic webpage with Puppeteer works on localhost but not Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, web-scraping, puppeteer, chromium

Node.js app with Express, deployed on Heroku. It's just dynamic webpages. Loading static webpages works fine.

Loading dynamic webpages works on localhost, but on Heroku it throws me `code=H12`, `desc="Request timeout"`, `service=30000ms`, `status=503`.

In addition, fresh after doing `heroku restart` or making a deployment, there always seems to be one instance of a `status=200` that loads only the static portion of a dynamic webpage.

Screenshot of logs [here](https://i.postimg.cc/GdbtpbNx/Screenshot-1.png).

---

I've tried the following, which have all led to either the same or other unexpected results when deployed on Heroku (such as `Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)` and `code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response"`):

- Switching the Puppeteer Heroku buildpack I was using. I've tried the ones mentioned in [this troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-on-heroku) and [this comment](https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/issues/381#issuecomment-708862941).
- Adding `headless: true` in Puppeteer's `launch` arguments.
- Adding the `--no-sandbox`, `--disable-setuid-sandbox`, `--single-process`, and `--no-zygote` flags in `args` of Puppeteer's `launch` arguments. (Reference: [this comment](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/758#issuecomment-328906039) & [this comment](https://dev.to/aurium/comment/1bdj6))
- Setting the `waitUntil` argument in Puppeteer's `goto` function to `domcontentloaded`, `networkidle0` and `networkidle2`. (Reference: [this comment](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1666#issuecomment-354224942))
- Passing a `timeout` argument in Puppeteer `goto` function; I've tried `30000` and `60000` specifically, as well as `0` per [this comment](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/782#issuecomment-655004725).
- Using the `waitForSelector` function.
- Clearing Heroku's build cache, as per [this article](https://help.heroku.com/18PI5RSY/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache).
- Printing the `url` variable (see my code below) in the console. Output is as expected.

---

I've observed that:

- With the code I have right now (see below), the `try-catch-finally` block never catches any error. It's always one of the following: I get an incomplete result (static portion of requested dynamic webpage), *or* the app crashes (`code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response"`). So I haven't been able to get anything out of attempting to print `exception` in the console from within the `catch` block.

---

Any ideas on how I could get this to work?

```
const app = express();
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
let port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
let browser;

...

app.listen(port, async() => {
  browser = await puppeteer
    .launch({
      timeout: 0,
      headless: true,
      args: [
        "--no-sandbox",
        "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
        "--single-process",
        "--no-zygote",
      ],
    });
});

...

app.get("/appropriate-route-name", async (req, res) => {
  let url = req.query.url;
  let page = await browser.newPage();

  try {
    await page.goto(url, {
      waitUntil: "networkidle2",
    });
    res.send({ data: await page.content() });
  } catch (exception) {
    res.send({ data: null });
  } finally {
    await browser.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Try this buildpack `https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack.git`

Comment: @AmitP yup, that's actually what I'm using right now. no luck

Comment: can you show how you are starting/initializing your server?

Comment: @AmitP locally, I run `node the-file-in-question.js`. for Heroku, I ensure that the deployed app has my latest commits (`git push heroku main`). then I access `the-app-in-question.herokuapp.com`. I do `heroku logs --tail` to view the logs as I access the deployed app. anytime the deployed app crashes, I do `heroku restart`. is this what you're asking?

Comment: I mean, how are you making a server in nodejs? If you are using `https` module, try using `http` module instead.

Comment: @AmitP I'm using `express`; given `const app = express()`, I set `app.listen(port, fn)` to port `3000`, and use `app.get(url, fn)` for routing.

Comment: Dont set port yourself, use `process.env.PORT` for port, heroku assigns a port for your app. [Check this out](https://help.heroku.com/P1AVPANS/why-is-my-node-js-app-crashing-with-an-r10-error#:~:text=Heroku%20dynos%20expose%20a%20dynamic%20port%20for%20your%20app%20to%20bind%20to.%20This%20value%20is%20exposed%20in%20the%20%24PORT%20env%20var.%20You%20must%20change%20your%20code%20to%20bind%20to%20this%20port%20instead.%20For%20example)

Comment: @AmitP ah yeah my bad, I do indeed set the port to `process.env.PORT || 3000`.

Comment: umm... Did you try clearing the build cache just in case? [Check this](https://help.heroku.com/18PI5RSY/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache)

Comment: Also, share the complete log you get from heroku

Comment: @AmitP I've cleared the build cache as suggested, no changes. I've edited in some additional info in the question, there's a link to a screenshot of the logs there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237492/discussion-between-amit-p-and-lefrost).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to get it to work by using [`user-agents`](https://github.com/intoli/user-agents). Dynamic pages now load just fine on Heroku; requests don't time out every single time anymore.

```
const app = express();
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
let port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var userAgent = require("user-agents");

...

app.get("/route-name", async (req, res) => {
  let url = req.query.url;
  let browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ["--no-sandbox"],
  });
  let page = await browser.newPage();

  try {
    await page.setUserAgent(userAgent.toString()); // added this
    await page.goto(url, {
      timeout: 30000,
      waitUntil: "newtorkidle2", // or "networkidle0", depending on what you need
    });
    res.send({ data: await page.content() });

  } catch (e) {
    res.send({ data: null });

  } finally {
    await browser.close();
  }
});
```